# JOIN with condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a view that returns results of a query. The output looks something like this:

```
ORDER_ID    DESC  Package_Route_ID 
    123      ABC  212
    456      XYZ  175
```

I have another table that has `full order ID` for some of the `ORDER_ID`s. The table looks like following:

```
ORDER_ID     FULL_ORDER_ID
    456      45678
```

So I want to display `FULL_ORDER_ID` if `ORDER_ID` from both the results matches or else it should return `ORDER_ID` from view.

Desired output:

```
ORDER_ID     DESC  Package_Route_ID 
    123      ABC   212
    45678    XYZ   175
```

Comment: You are looking for `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `COALESCE`.

Comment: Can you posted the query you have tried?

Comment: @tommyO I was on right track just because of other predicates in `WHERE` I was missing some records. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `left outer join`

```
select isnull(od.FULL_ORDER_ID, v.ORDER_ID) ORDER_ID, v.[DESC], v.Package_Route_ID 
from view v
left join ordertable od on od.ORDER_ID = v.ORDER_ID;
```